# MySQL connection failed in MediaWiki installation but successful from command-line

Tags: mysql, fedora, mediawiki

Installing a standard MediaWiki installation on a server: `itwiki.ourdomain.com`

Using MySQL on a different server: `mysql.ourdomain.com`

I've created the user `wikiuser` and the schema/db: `itwiki` and assigned all the proper permissions, etc for the user to that schema.

During the MediaWiki installation I get the following error:

```
Attempting to connect to database server as wikiuser...failed with error [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql.ourdomain.com' (13).
```

I have the correct hostname, user, password and schema entered though. In order to verify my user permissions, I reverted back to the shell on the same web server:

```
> mysql -u wikiuser -p -h mysql.ourdomain.com
```

And that allowed me to successfully connect to the database when I entered the password.

So something weird is going on here. I can connect just fine from the command line, but MW is not allowing me to connect. Any thoughts on where I should be looking to troubleshoot this behavior?

Comment: It's not clear from your question but did you use the command line from the web server machine or another machine?

Comment: From the web server via Putty.

Comment: Do you have php-mysql installed and enabled?

Comment: phpinfo() says yes.

Comment: You could try writing a simple PHP page that just connects to MySQL server. If this doesn't work, add debugging information, make PHP write a stack trace, etc. If the simple PHP file works then it looks like a bug in mediawiki. Maybe a specific authentication algorithm (not md5 based)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be selinux preventing httpd from making the connection

Comment: `sestatus` reports `disabled`

Comment: SELinux was the problem. Even though it was reporting as disabled, when I looked in the Firewall config it showed SELinux still as `enabled`. Setting it to `permissive` fixed the problem. Man... Trying to troubleshoot SELinux-related problems on a server is such a pain.